# Do many files in a single directory cause longer loading time under Apache?

Tags: php, apache, unix

Even if there seem to exist a few duplicate questions, I think this one is unique. I'm not asking if there are any limits, it's only about performance drawbacks in context of Apache. Or unix file system in general.

Lets say if I request a file from an Apache server

```
http://example.com/media/example.jpg
```

does it matter how many files there are in the same directory "media"?

The reason I'm asking is that my PHP application generates images on the fly.

Once created, it places it at the same location the PHP script would trigger due to ModRewrite. If the file exists, Apache will skip the whole PHP execution and directly serve the static image instead. Some kind of gateway cache if you want to call it that way.

Apache has basically two things to do:

1. Check if the file exists
2. Serve the file or forward the request to PHP

Till now, I have about 25.000 files with about 8 GB in this single directory. I expect it to grow at least 10 times in the next years.

While I don't face any issues managing these files, I have the slight feeling that it keeps getting slower when requesting them via HTTP. So I wondered if this is really what happens or if it's just my subjective impression.

Comment: It depends on the filesystem and how it searches for files in a directory; if it uses linear searching it will be slow, if it's indexed the number of files is less of a problem. It's not really specific to Apache (or any other server). This would probably be a better question for unix.SE or ServerFault.com.

Comment: Ok, yeah you're right. Basically it always takes longer to search through a larger set of files. I thought maybe file systems could magically optimize or cache file requests, making their actual hierarchy obsolete.

Comment: In fact there is a directory cache, so it's not quite as bad as I suggested. But loading a large directory into cache is costly, too.

Comment: Too many file in a single directory is usually not a good idea. May I suggested you to separate them in sub directories? As you are generating the filenames, you may also use some strategy to put a file in a directory deduced from its name (like some hash function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most file systems based on the Berkeley FFS will degrade in performance with large numbers of files in one directory due to multiple levels of indirection.

I don't know about other file systems like HFS or NTFS, but my suspicion is that they may well suffer from the same issue.

I once had to deal with a similar issue and ended up using a map for the files.

I think it was something like `md5 myfilename-00001` yielding (for example): `e5948ba174d28e80886a48336dcdf4a4` which I then put into a file named `e5/94/8ba174d28e80886a48336dcdf4a4`.  Then a map file mapped 'myfilename-00001' to 'e5/94/8ba174d28e80886a48336dcdf4a4'.  This not-quite-elegant solution worked for my purposes and it only took a little bit of code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was not that I didn't knew how to split these files into multiple directories, I just wanted to know if it's even necessary. And yes, seems like it is :)